# why is col-xs-* no effect when zomming out browser?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="background-color: red;">
        <p>lskdflsjdlfsjdlf sdljsdsdfs dfsdfsdfsf</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="background-color: green;">
        <p>lskdflsjdlfsjdlfsdljsdsdfsd sdfsdfsf</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="background-color: blue;">
        <p>lsdflksjdfsldkfjlsd jflskjd</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <p>lsdjflksjdfkmsld mflsd mlksdf</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

effect picture when zooming out browser:
[image]

This is sample part,but I don't know what is happened?

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason. My bootstrap version is 4.0.0 and its extra small is .col- rather than .col-xs-.

Comment: FWIW it works as desired if you include the `col` class on the columns... https://jsfiddle.net/gy4uncgp/5/